# HTML code for strip table works but not with SQL msdb email

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've generate HTML email from SQL server and formatted the tables in "striped format" with CSS. SQL part is working perfectly. Problem is, when I save generated HTML code in notepad and run it in browser, the striped formatting works fine but the same do not work when comes in email and user view it in Outlook.

Please see screenshot: ideally the second row (even rows) should be formatted with white background.

Please help me to fix it.

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css"> table.blueTable {  font-family: Eras Medium ITC, Eras Medium ITC, Eras Medium ITC;  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;  background-color: #EEEEEE;  width: auto;  text-align: left;  border-collapse: collapse; } table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;  padding: 3px 2px; } table.blueTable tbody td {  font-size: 10pt; text-align: right; } table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) {  background: #FFFFFF; } table.blueTable thead {  background: #1C6EA4;  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%); } table.blueTable thead th {  font-size: 10pt;  font-weight: normal;  color: #FFFFFF; } table.blueTable tfoot td {  font-size: 10pt; } table.blueTable tfoot .links {  text-align: right; } table.blueTable tfoot .links a{  display: inline-block;  background: #1C6EA4;  color: #FFFFFF;  padding: 2px 8px;  border-radius: 5px; }</style>
   <body style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Eras Medium ITC;">
      Dear Team, <br /><br /> Please find below daily Coke Campaign visibility till <strong>Oct 16, 2020</strong> <br /><br />
      <p style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Eras Medium ITC;"><strong>MTD Summary:</strong></p>
      <table class="bluetable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>MTD Date</th>
               <th>Trxn Count</th>
               <th>Customers Count</th>
               <th>Disbursed Amount</th>
               <th>Avg. Cashback per User</th>
               <th>New Base</th>
               <th>Rejoiner Base</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>16-Oct-20</td>
               <td>545530</td>
               <td>45433</td>
               <td>56000095</td>
               <td>1213.27</td>
               <td>123268</td>
               <td>22005</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />
      <p style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Eras Medium ITC;"><strong>Day-on-Day Summary:</strong></p>
      <table class="bluetable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Date</th>
               <th>Trxn Count</th>
               <th>Customers Count</th>
               <th>Disbursed Amount</th>
               <th>Avg. Cashback per User</th>
               <th>New Base in 5 Days</th>
               <th>Rejoiner Base in 5 Days</th>
               <th>Old Base</th>
               <th>New Base (%)</th>
               <th>Rejoiner Base (%)</th>
               <th>Old Base (%)</th>
            </tr>
            </tdead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>13-Oct-20</td>
               <td>5000</td>
               <td>300</td>
               <td>50022323</td>
               <td>16.74545</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>0.00 %</td>
               <td>0.00 %</td>
               <td>100.00 %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>14-Oct-20</td>
               <td>3323292</td>
               <td>3173232</td>
               <td>3,935</td>
               <td>62.4</td>
               <td>63239</td>
               <td>111232</td>
               <td>13732</td>
               <td>61.77 %</td>
               <td>30.02 %</td>
               <td>9.22 %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>15-Oct-20</td>
               <td>233041</td>
               <td>1333775</td>
               <td>20333740</td>
               <td>1122.7</td>
               <td>386668</td>
               <td>57444</td>
               <td>8134</td>
               <td>21.86 %</td>
               <td>32.34 %</td>
               <td>45.80 %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>16-Oct-20</td>
               <td>34092</td>
               <td>356090</td>
               <td>315370</td>
               <td>102.2</td>
               <td>6331</td>
               <td>9403</td>
               <td>10517</td>
               <td>20.49 %</td>
               <td>30.42 %</td>
               <td>49.09 %</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br /><br />
   </body>
   </head>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Might be that `:nth-child()` doesn't work in Outlook. Keep in mind that an email client is not a web client. There are a *lot* of quirks.

Comment: Might be, but is there any alternative for that?

Comment: Do it the old school way. Add even and odd classes for each row.